# Intellij Jpa console db schema

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

When I want make query in Intellij JPA console I get error that `relation "topic" does not exist`. Jpql query `select t from Topic t`. I'm using spring boot, I added jpa to module, persistence toolbar works well, but jpa console doesn't. My thougs that JPA Console not find in right db schema, but datasource selected corect.

JPA console print:
[2019-07-19 12:49:59] [42P01] ERROR: relation "topic" does not exist
[2019-07-19 12:49:59] Position: 60

Comment: Apparently there is no table named `topic` in your database. You need to create one first

Comment: But in database also in database toolbar is visible :/

Comment: Maybe you quoted it when you created it? `"Topic"` a different table name than `topic`

Comment: tables made automaticaly by orm

Comment: Then your obfuscation layer should be able to generate the correct SQL queries.

Comment: Can be problem that I don't have set naming strategy on entity manager factory in persistence toolbar? I don't have idea what I should chose..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196708/discussion-between-andrew-sneck-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Comment: Add more details: what is the database, how you define mappings? Can you run same query from code? Check e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626989/jpa-error-relation-does-not-exist

Comment: Yes I'm able run same query from code.  But I don't have set naming strategy... screen: [link](https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/07/22/t8Ca.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake in connection to database. I had in field Database value `postgres`, I replace by `chatapp` - it is correct schema, and now it works well

[image: Database settings]

Answer (score 7):

Did you do all those steps?:

[image]

(The IDEA version is 2019.1)

Comment: very nice animation, I have all set as you show, but if i try hibernate console it ends by exception: `[2019-07-20 23:11:30] org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in FILE C:\Users\ondra\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\compiler\agent-chat.87f53839\.generated\Jpa_Console\agent-chat.main-hibernate-1563657080743.cfg.xml. Message: null
[2019-07-20 23:11:30] javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.`

Comment: @AndrewSneck Maybe it's related to [JAXB-API and Java version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51916221/5380322) issue somehow?

Comment: I add this dependecies: 
    `implementation "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11"
    implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11"
    implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11"
    implementation "javax.activation:activation:1.1.1"`
and hibernate console now show same error as jpa console specifically:  ERROR: relation "topic" does not exist